# jquery $("#form").submit() not getting called

Tags: php, jquery, recaptcha

I have a form on a page that requires a captcha if the user has a blocked attribute set in a database.

```
$("#expressform").submit(function() {
    if($("#op").val() == "")
            return false;
    if($("#tagbar").val() == "")
            return false;
    $.post("getallowed.php", function(data) {
            if(data == "true")
                    submitNormal();
            else if(data == "false"){
                    displayCaptcha();
            }
    });
    return false;
});
```

If the user is not allowed, the displayCaptcha function is called instead of just submitting the form.

```
function displayCaptcha(){
    $.post("expresscaptcha.php", function(data) {
            var string = data;
            $("#expressformdiv").html(string);
            Recaptcha.create("xxxxxxxxxxx", "captcha",
                    {
                            theme: "red",
                            callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
                    }
            );
    });
}
```

This function posts to a php script that returns a new type of form that returns the html for a new form with the id expressformcaptcha. Here is the php script.

```
<?php
echo <<<_END
<form id="expressformcaptcha">
    //other form elements
    <div id="captchadiv"><div id="captcha"></div></div>
</form>
_END;
?>
```

All of this works fine, the captcha displays, etc. However, the alert in the following never gets called. Why?

```
$("#expressformcaptcha").submit(function() {
    alert("FORM SUBMITTED");
});
```

Does it have something to do with the captcha being there that screws with jquery? When submit the form, instead of the alert, the page just refreshes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) as `expressformcaptcha` is injected into the DOM at a later time.

```
$("#expressformcaptcha").live('submit', function() {
    alert("FORM SUBMITTED");
});
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you! If I may ask, why do I have to use live?

Comment: That's because at the time the event is bound that element is not present in the DOM. Please mark as accepted when you get the chance, thanks!

Comment: You don't have to use live; he mentioned delegate as another option! In some scenarios it doesn't matter much, but in general .delegate() is MUCH better (handles event propagation better, performs better due to listening on fewer elements); I would get in the habit of using .delegate() in situations where .live() would also work.